# Canonical duplicate for "Why do predictions vary less than observations?"

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Two recent questions:

- [Regression - variance of predictions much lower than variance of target](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/391307/1352), which I voted to close as a duplicate of
- [Regression predictions show far less variance than expected](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/390210/1352)

I am sure we have had this question before, but [a simple search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+of+predictions+lower+than+variance+of+observations) did't show anything that seemed useful, nor was there anything among the "related" threads.

Do we have a canonical duplicate for this kind of questions? If not, should we have one?

Comment: "Why does my predictive model explain less than 100% of the variance?" is IMHO too general for a canonical question.

Comment: @amoeba: and it's a different question.

Comment: Hmm, why is it different?

Comment: Maybe a general question on "what is regression to the mean, and what does it have to do with linear regression"?

Comment: @amoeba: the difference is that the questions in question deal with out-of-sample predictions, whereas explained variance deals with in-sample fits. (Yes, I'll admit the two concepts are related. But I don't think someone posting the first kind of question will understand how an answer to the second kind will apply to *their* question.)